# performance issues when using mysql_query with mysql_fetch_row

Tags: php, mysql

I'm not very familiar with mySQL and php. Helping out a friend with their performance issues.

They have a file called report.php which queries the database and then outputs all the rows and columns from the query.

This execution seems to lock up the db and cause CPU usage to spike to 100% when multiple users execute for reports. Is there anything obvious I'm missing over here ?

The structure of report.php is as follows

```
include('../settings2.inc');

$type=$_GET['report'];


if(isset($_GET['report']))
{
   switch($type){
    case uuppgroup:     $export=mysql_query("select * from uuppgroupdetails order by id");
                        break;

    case Beneficiary:   $export=mysql_query("select * from uupp_ben_details order by ben_id");
                            break;

    (many other switch cases over here
..
..

}


$fields = mysql_num_fields ( $export );  

for ( $i = 0; $i < $fields; $i++ ) 
{     
  $header .= mysql_field_name( $export , $i ) . "\t"; 
}  

while( $row = mysql_fetch_row( $export ) ) 
{     
  $line = '';     
  foreach( $row as $value )     
  {                                                     
    if ( ( !isset( $value ) ) || ( $value == "" ) )         
    {             
       $value = "\t";         
    }         
    else         
    {             
      $value = str_replace( '"' , '""' , $value );             
      $value = '"' . $value . '"' . "\t";         
    }         
    $line .= $value;     
  }     
  $data .= trim( $line ) . "\n"; 
} 

$data = str_replace( "\r" , "" , $data );   }

$vExcelFileName=$type.".xls";
#$vExcelFileName="export". ".doc";
header("Content-type: application/x-ms-download"); //#-- build header to download the excel file
header("Content-Disposition: attachment; filename=$vExcelFileName");
header('Cache-Control: public');
print "$header\n$data"; 
/*
}
```

Comment: show the tables which are used select statement because the main cause may due to `*` instead of few columns which you required. And also please use pdo instead of mysql function reason one is it will be deprecated and reason two is you can port to another sql like postgresql

Answer (score -2):

Make sure to include:

```
mysql_close($dbcon);
```

If these files are being produced on a regular basis, to stop the constant fetching to your database, if you ran a CRON job every 30minutes/hour to generate these files, and then when someone requests them, they're available in a folder of your choice such as "/downloads/reports/Beneficiary.pdf"

Since your code looks fine (from the parts I can see) my best guess is that some of your other queries might be breaking it. The only thing I can guess is that with multiple users simultaneously requesting data from the database, it hangs when trying to process (thus the 100% cpu usage)

Comment: It should be as comment not as answer. It doesn't solve the issue, this is just an information.

Comment: As you can see I have only 39, I can't comment. However, if he tries this and it does solve it, then it's an answer, else he can comment on this, and seek further assistance. I'm currently looking through his code now to see what else can be achieved.

Comment: So you need to earn reputation, but you shouldn't post comments as answer. If you cannot, just don't do it if you don't have possible solution or explanation. Your answer must be edited.

Comment: And I've been trying, I've started yesterday and already answered about 10 questions, 2 of which were deemed "correct"

Comment: But if people see it as a comment, not an answer it will get down voted and you'll lose that reputation!

Comment: So, at fear of losing reputation, I shouldn't try to help someone?

Comment: It provides a solution, which should help him solve his problem.